# Natural language loops in the shell

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a natural way to run a command in a loop on a set of inputs without explicitly using a loop construct? I mean in a way that resembles how we talk in English.

For example,

```
some-command -a john,jane -b doe,roe
```

instead of

```
for a in john jane; do
   for b in doe roe; do
     some-command -a $a -b $b
   done
done
```

Can you do this in `bash`? Is there another shell that has a feature like this?

It doesn't have to be the exact same syntax I put here, but something idiomatic that's not as bulky as the nested loop.

Comment: This is going to be entirely up to the command and/or the shell. Is there some problem you're actually trying to solve, or are you just theorizing about something you wished were the case?

Comment: I know. I'm dealing with a command that doesn't have that feature, so I'm looking for something in the shell.

Comment: My example is `kubectl --context=context1,context2 --namespace=ns1,ns2 get pod`

Comment: *nix's philosophy is very heavy on customization, such as writing your own scripts and commands. So you/one could perhaps write your/one's own?

Comment: also besides looking at shells you could consider scripting languages . Rebol is perhaps a scripting language that is meant to be natural.  But maybe sometimes attempts  at a language to be more natural can sometimes make it tricky to get the syntax right 'cos no language is forgiving if you make a minor syntactical mishap so it's never natural.

Comment: @barlop makes sense. I'll look up Rebol though. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the `for` loop in a shell function. Here's a rather fragile implementation based on the example in your question:

```
loop ()
{
    for i in `echo $3 |tr ',' ' '`;
    do
        for j in `echo $5 |tr ',' ' '`;
        do
            $1 $2 $i $4 $j;
        done;
    done;
}
```

Then, the function would be called as `loop some-command -a john,jane -b doe,roe`. For instance:

```
$ for i in /{bin,media}; do for j in /{srv,tmp/tmp}; do \ls -d $i $j; done; done
/bin  /srv
/bin  /tmp/tmp
/media  /srv
/media  /tmp/tmp
$ loop ls -d /bin,/media "" /srv,/tmp/tmp
/bin  /srv
/bin  /tmp/tmp
/media  /srv
/media  /tmp/tmp
$ _
```

Comment: well, I think that's a step in the right direction. but you're assuming that it's always gonna be 2 levels of nested `for`s. there's no way to make that dynamic?

Comment: thanks for the brace expansion example. that gave me an idea!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a better answer, but here is an interim "solution".

After learning about brace expansion in bash, this is what I came up with. Unfortunately you have to escape all special characters in the command or use quotes:

```
eval 'some-command -a '{john,jane}' -b '{doe,roe}';'
eval some-command\ -a\ {john,jane}\ -b\ {doe,roe}\;
```

For example,

```
eval 'kubectl --context='{context1,context2}' --namespace='{ns1,ns2}' get pod;'
eval kubectl\ --context={context1,context2}\ --namespace={ns1,ns2}\ get\ pod\;
```

Still somewhat awkward. Not sure if other shells have a better option.